# If-else List of lists comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have the following list of lists:

```
list1 = [[1,"one"],[2,"two"],[3,"three]]
```

I would like to have output of:

```
list2 = [[11,"one"],[2,"two"],[3,"three"]]
```

List comprehension with an if-else statement seems to be a good option for this.

```
list2 = [x if x[0] != 1 else 11 for x[0] in list1]
```

However, I get the NameError that 'x' is not defined. How should I define x?

Comment: You mean `for x in list1`. `x[0]` isn't a legal way to bind to a name.

Comment: No, as if I do this, it outputs list2 = [11,[2,"two"],[3,"three"]]

Comment: No, you currently get a `NameError` and the above comment solves this.

Comment: [x if x[0] != 1 else [11, x[1]] for x in list1]

Comment: @gumrana  the above comment of Carcigenicate does solve the error, but it does not solve my problem. All solved now thanks to Mady Daby  and ThePyGuy! Thanks a ton guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do `for x[0] in <iterable>`, you need to use the entire inner-list/sequence. To get the result you are looking for, you can either use second level list comprehension, or just the list concatenation with one level of comprehension as below:

```py
>>> [x if x[0]!=1 else [11]+x[1:] for x in list1]
[[11, 'one'], [2, 'two'], [3, 'three']]
```

Answer (score 3):

With a list comprehension, you have to rebuild the entire sublist, as there is no way to mutate a list *and* get the result with a single expression:

```
list2 = [x if x[0] != 1 else [x[0]+10, x[1]] for x in list1]
```

(Use `*x` instead of `x[1]` to generalize to longer sublists.)

With an ordinary `for` loop, you can simply mutate the existing list, if you don't need a shallow copy.

```
for x in list1:
    if x[0] == 1:
        x[0] += 10
```

(And in every case, you can replace addition by 10 with a hard-coded 11, since you know the exact value of `x[0]` if you condition succeeds.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a couple of changes in code. I found the following issues:

- You need to iterate over the entire list, hence you need the line: `x in list1` instead of `x[0] in list1`
- You need to add back both elements of the sublist, currently you directly added x without modifications

`list2 = [[11, x[1]] if x[0] == 1 else x for x in list1]`